# Can I set PowerShell as 'default' in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, powershell, batch-file

I would like, by default, for PowerShell to be launched instead of Command when, say, running a batch file, or when I "Open Command Window Here", etc.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I don't think powershell can interpret batch files, so you probably shouldn't make it open those.

Answer (score 9):

I just did a very quick test and the following registry entry will add a "PowerShell here" item to the context menu of all folders in explorer:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\PowerShellHere]
@="&PowerShell here"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\PowerShellHere\command]
@="cmd.exe /c start \"PS\" powershell.exe -NoExit -Command \"cd \\\"%1\\\"\""
```

Just import it into the registry.
I am using `cmd.exe` to bootstrap powershell in order to avoid having to hard-code the path.

Regarding cmd scripts/batch files. I think it does not make much sense to run CMD scripts within PowerShell by default. But it might be possible as well by modifying `HKCR\cmdfile\shell\open` registry key

Comment: Thanks! I'll give these a try tonight. The only reason I want scripts to open in powershell is for consistency and cooperation with my windowing tools. You are right that there is no inherent practical reason. ;)

Answer (score 0):

You're not going to get very far with running CMD batch files in PowerShell.

You can try changing the `%COMSPEC%` variable to point at `powershell.exe` using `setx`, but I don't think it will take you long to realise that this is a really bad idea and change it back again.

save the file as *.ps1 instead of *.bat
and it will use powershell

Comment: Why is it a bad idea?  Just curious.

Comment: @afrazier: I have not experimented with changing `%COMSPEC%` to a non-CMD-compatible shell, but I assume that changing it to PowerShell would result in `.cmd`/`.bat` files trying to execute in PowerShell, so *they would* fail.  I have installed a lot of software which needed to use batch files, so doing that would be a bad idea.  Also, I am a bit biased, as I use CMD all the time (actually, TCC, which is an expanded superset), for everyday file managing - I only use PowerShell for system stuff, although I have a lot more to learn, as it is so powerful in comparison.

Comment: Just for giggles, I've changed `%ComSpec%` to point to PowerShell on my Win7 system.  The first couple `.cmd` files I tested work just fine.  They involve `cmd`-specific constructs (`for`, Variable manipulation, `if`), so PS is apparently smart enough to know when it needs to invoke `cmd.exe`.

Comment: For example, changing `%ComSpec%` to powershell breaks the mercurial version control commands.